# Outlook "Select Contacts" form: what controls does it use?

Tags: c#, forms, outlook

The Outlook 2010 "Select Names: Contacts" form (for instance, when you click "To..." when composing a new email) seems to use a custom listbox to display multiple columns of information. What control is this? Essentially, how can I re-create this sort of functionality (using C# if that matters)?

Image:

[image]

Is it a single listbox that spaces each column with padding? Currently for similar functionality I have multiple separate listboxes and it is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a `ListView` control with the `View` property set to `Details`. There's an `ImageList` control associated with it in order to provide the small icons beside each item.